# Why was I suspended for a week?

Tags: discussion

I had my Unix&Linux (and Meta) access suspended for a week (although my U&L Meta rep is still 1).

Is there an information source I missed that would have explained why? Was I unacceptably rude? Did I post too many identical answers?

I understand that a suspension is SE's way of saying "Don't do that", but unless I know what "that" is, it's hard to behave better.

How can I correct my behavior to avoid another suspension?

Comment: You should have received an email message and also an SE inbox notification when you were suspended. Are you saying neither of those things happened? I also tested this by suspending a sock account and confirmed reception of both messages.

Comment: I want to help you; a private message was sent at the time, and it'd be my preference to continue using that channel instead of publicly Meta, since we don't generally discuss suspensions publicly. If it's impossible to communicate privately, I'm open to discussing it here, with the goal being to educate everyone on what we see as acceptable vs unacceptable behavior.

Comment: (in other news, the "Meta rep" issue appeared to be temporary; its rep is apparently recalculated on some separate schedule; sometime in the past 30 minutes or so, it was synced back up to your main-site rep)

Comment: @waltinator, can you confirm that you received neither an email nor an inbox notification?

Comment: @terdon I confirm that I received neither an email nor an inbox notification.

Comment: @waltinator I'm really surprised that you didn't get an SE notification! We're asking SE for help to see if something went wrong. I'm the meantime, would you humor me and see if a message shows up circa March 1 in your network inbox? From your [profile](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11135/waltinator), click the "Profiles" drop-down at the upper right and choose "Network profile", then the "inbox" section. Depending on how much activity your SE inbox gets, you may have to click through the pages to get back to March 1. Thank you!

Comment: Hello @waltinator please make sure that you have a verified email linked to your account so that you can receive notifications and emails from us. If you have any other questions please feel free to contact the Community Team by utilizing the [Contact](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) button at the bottom of the page.

Comment: You can see the mod message we sent you here, @waltinator: https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/message/315#315. You should also be able to find it in your notifications, which are available in the top bar inbox link.